# How can I add extra content section to my opencart by using module?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

Recently I'm facing problem with my opencart project. I can add extra content to my opencart home page by modifying the home.tpl file

But I want to Add functionality to my admin -> extentions -> modules for control my sections.

But I am new in opencart platform. Can anyone give me an idea that how can I do this?

Comment: \admin\view\template\extension\module\account.tpl file handles the module list page. You can add check box and script in that page.

Answer (score 2):

I was in this trouble few days then I've found a blog post where they describe briefly how to create custom module for opencart.

Here is the link. Hope it will be helpful for you too.

http://www.php-dev-zone.com/2015/02/opencart-custom-module-development.html

Comment: Thanks for your resource Giulio Bambini